# RequestBody POJO always empty

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I want to store some data from an HTML form (working with AngularJS) into my database, using Spring.
For this, I'm using the `@RequestBody` annotation with a POJO, but I can't make it work: my POJO is instancied, but it looks like the POJO attributes are not mapped with my form values (they are all null).

**Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createEntities", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Entity> createEntities(@RequestBody final EntityList resource, @RequestParam final String kind) {
    System.out.println("Creating entity for: " + kind);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(resource);
    List<Entity> newEntities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    System.out.println("Entity test = " + resource.getTest()); // Prints "Entity test = null"
    // Code below returns NullException
    //System.out.println("Entity list nb = " + resource.getEntity().size());
    if (resource.getEntities() != null && !resource.getEntities().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Entity list is OK");
        for (EntityForm eForm : resource.getEntities()) {
            if (eForm.getGrant() != null) {
                Entity ent = new Entity();
                if ("RTS".equals(kind)) {
                    ent.setDept(deptService.findByAbr(DeptEnum.RTS.name()));
                } else {
                    ent.setDept(deptService.findByAbr(DeptEnum.RTB.name()));
                }
                ent.setGrant(eForm.getGrant());
                ent.setCountry(eForm.getCountry());
                ent.setName(eForm.getName());
                ent = service.create(ent);
                newEntities.add(ent);
            }
        }
    }
    return newEntities;
}
```

`EntityList` is the POJO for my form. This POJO contains a list of `EntityForm` (+ a string for test purpose), which is a DTO for my database entity `Entity`.

**EntityList POJO :**

```
public class EntityList implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6335318686899794229L;
    private List<EntityForm> entities;
    private String test;

    public EntityList() {
        super();
    }

    public EntityList(List<EntityForm> entities, String test) {
        super();
        this.entities = entities;
        this.test = test;
    }

    public List<EntityForm> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(List<EntityForm> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    } 
}
```

I thought the problem came from a bad mapping between my list of entities in my form and my `List<EntityForm>` in my POJO, that's why I added a simple String to my POJO.

**AngularJS side**

Service :

```
app.factory("Entities", function($resource) {
    return $resource("api/auth/entities", null, 
    {
        createEntities: {method:'POST', url: "api/auth/entities/createEntities", params: { kind: '@kind' }, isArray:true}
    });
})
```

Controller :

```
$scope.EntForm = {};
$scope.EntForm.entities = [];
$scope.EntForm.test = "myTest";

/* ... */

$scope.saveEnt= function() {
    console.log($scope.EntForm);
    Entities.createEntities($scope.EntForm,{kind:"RTS"},function(res) {
        var msg = 'Entities created...'; 
        ngToast.create(msg); 
        $location.path("/entities");
    });
}
```

In my firefox console, I see that `$scope.EntForm` is correctly set (I have all my entity objects with the fields set, as well as the test string defined in the controller).

**Result**

All this code will display :

```
Creating entity for: RTS
Entity test = null
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the `@RequestParam final String kind` part from my Spring controller, and the param in AngularJS code.
To get the kind, I just added `$scope.EntForm.kind = "theValueIWant"` in my AngularJS controller.

I don't know if it's a good way to make it work in terms of good practice, but I get the `@RequestBody` content now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the POST payload with Firefox developer tools, is your custom `createEntities` method working correctly?

(Would have added this as a comment, but unfortunately I don't yet have enough reputation for that.)

Comment: If you're talking about sending my own POST request without using the AngularJS `createEntities` method, I can't. There is authentication requirements (I don't know how it works exactly as I didn't code this part of the app, so I can't just turn it off), every GET/POST request fails if I try to send it through Firefox dev tools.
Is there another way to test if my method works well ?

Comment: @Chugrothas I meant checking out the actual POST request contents that your AngularJS app generates. I haven't used Firefox in a while for development purposes, and don't even have it installed on my current computer so can't check it out myself, but using the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) you should be able to monitor for example the network requests made.

Then you should be able to check that your AngularJS app correctly populates the POST contents.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I totally forgot the existence of the Network viewer in Firefox console. I checked, and the POST request sent has the correct parameters (I can see my entities and the "test" string).

Comment: Ok, well that narrows it down a bit. :) Unfortunately I haven't been using Spring backend for a while, but perhaps it's an issue with JSON -> POJO deserialization. Perhaps [this SO question + answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930894) could help you to right direction?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LShetty sorry to comment in this way, but did you not read the part that said *(Would have added this as a comment, but unfortunately I don't yet have enough reputation for that.)*? Yes, I would have commented below openers post, had I had enough reputation (50+) at that time to be able to do so. But yes, thank you for your criticism.