# Is there any special configuration to cause "application/json" mime type to be accepted Tomcat 6.0 (Spring MVC 3.0)?

Tags: json, spring, tomcat, mime-types

Is there any special configuration one must do? or should it work out of the box?

e.g. should I add something like this to make it work?

```
 <mime-mapping>
    <extension>json</extension>
    <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Spring MVC will handle the MIME type itself if it's configured properly, but you'll need to tell us about your config before we can advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no special configuration, it accepts any application/json requests out of the box, I was suspecting the wrong issue.

See this other question of mine, it has the original issue and the surprising silly solution: [JQuery, Spring MVC @RequestBody and JSON - making it work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make Tomcat serve .json files with the right mime type then yes, you will need to add that mime type declaration to the *conf/web.xml* file.

If you're serving dynamically generated JSON then it really shouldn't matter: you can set any mime type using the `setContentType` function.

Comment: I'm trying to accept JSON requests (of type application/json)

Comment: Ah. What failure are you seeing?

Comment: This question / answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together was the cause, and I suspected that I have a mapping issue (I got null instead of a response) but it seems it's not this. so the question can be closed...

Comment: make sure to empty your browser cache after restarting! cf. HTTP code shouldn't be 3xx