# how to get the JSON data in Spring controller?

Tags: java, json, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I know it is a simple one . But couldn't find a solution.

My jQuery-ajax will be ,

```
var json = {"message":"Message123","time":"time123","name":"test123"}

data : JSON.stringify(json),
```

My Spring controller will be ,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "chat.html", method=RequestMethod.GET )
public @ResponseBody String getChat() {

System.out.println("Entered in to the controller ");

String name == ???
String msg == ???
String time == ???

//Process the functionality using the msg,name,time 

    return "Json String";
}
```

How can I get the values of the name, message , time.

Hope our stack members will help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON in Spring MVC using Jackson JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019562/parsing-json-in-spring-mvc-using-jackson-json)

Comment: @mthmulders So you are saying that `@RequestBody` will solve my problem.Right ?

Comment: I'm saying your question has already been asked before, and it was answered thoroughly. Using `@RequestBody` is part of the answer, indeed.

Comment: ok . But I was not aware of that answer.So only asked a question.Sorry...

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates to learn more about asking questions and duplicate questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
var json = {"message":"Message123","time":"time123","name":"test123"}
data : JSON.stringify(json) should have a key , 

data : {json:{"message":"Message123","time":"time123","name":"test123"}},
url:/json/test
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"json/test"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String jsonTest(String json){
       JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(json);
        String m = jsonObject.get("message").toString();
        String t = jsonObject.get("time").toString();
        String n = jsonObject.get("name").toString();
    }
```

I use the `net.sf.json.JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.Json jar from this [link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar) ...

Then try this code, I have done is in my current project and is working fine and efficiently

```
 var json = {"message":"Message123","time":"time123","name":"test123"}
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/chat.html",
    data: "jsonObject="+json,
    success: function(response) {
       // your success code
    },
    error: function(e) {
        // your error code
    }
});
```

In controller change your code like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat.html", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public @ResponseBody String getChat(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(req.getParameter("jsonObject"));
    } catch(JSONException _instance) {
        // Exception Handle Message
    }

    System.out.println("Entered in to the controller ");
    String name ="" , msg = "", time = "";
    if(jsonObject.has("name")) {
       name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    }

    ... // Do it for other variables also

    //Process the functionality using the msg,name,time 

    return "Json String";
}
```