# Spring mvc RequestMapping from json

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble creating the appropriate RequestParams for the following Json String:

```
{
  "input": [
    {
      "personAdres": {
        "plaats": "Amsterdam",
        "straat": "Grietenstraat",
        "huisnummer": "12",
        "postcode": "4512UN""
      },
      "interesses": [
        "gas_station",
        "soccer"
      ]
    },
    {
      "personAdres": {
        "plaats": "Arnhem",
        "straat": "Koningsweg",
        "huisnummer": "3",
        "postcode": "1953AA"
      },
      "interesses": [
        "gas_station",
        "soccer"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"input", "personAdres", "plaats", "straat", "huisnummer", "postcode", "interesses"})
    public
    @ResponseBody`enter code here`
    String getMovie(
            @RequestParam(value = "input") String[] input,
            @RequestParam(value = "personAdres") String[] personAdres,
            @RequestParam(value = "plaats") String plaats,
            @RequestParam(value = "straat") String straat,
            @RequestParam(value = "huisnummer") String huisnummer,
            @RequestParam(value = "postcode") String postcode,
            @RequestParam(value = "interesses")String[] interesses,
            ModelMap model
    )
```

That doens't seem to work. I'm getting the following error.

No matching handler method found for servlet request:

Can anyone help me out to create the right requestParams.

Edit: this seems to work

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dateSuggestie")
public class DateController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getMovie(
            @RequestParam(value = "input[0][personAdres][plaats]") String p0Plaats,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[0][personAdres][straat]") String p0Straat,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[0][personAdres][huisnummer]") String p0HuisNummer,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[0][personAdres][postcode]") String p0PostCode,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[0][interesses][]") String[] p0Interesses,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[1][personAdres][plaats]") String p1Plaats,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[1][personAdres][straat]") String p1Straat,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[1][personAdres][huisnummer]") String p1HuisNummer,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[1][personAdres][postcode]") String p1PostCode,
            @RequestParam(value = "input[1][interesses][]") String[] p1Interesses) {
```

Comment: Can you paste a full code of this controller? I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: first try to remove the params condition from `RequestMapping` and see  whether it works.

Comment: I'm not actually sending json i was just representing it that way so it would be more readable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are sending JSON to your controller not request parameters. `@RequestParam` and `@ModelAttribute` only work when data is submitted as request parameters.

Your JSON is send to the controller as the request body. For this spring has the `@RequestBody` annotation. In general you don't want to parse the body yourself but use a framework to do the heavy lifting for you. For this purpose libraries like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) exist.

These frameworks also integrate with Spring as one can read in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-mapping-json-converter).

You need to construct an object which is a Java representation of your JSON so that Jackson can do the conversion. You can then rewrite your controller method to something like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getMovie(@RequestBody YourObject) { ... }
```

Comment: more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019562/parsing-json-in-spring-mvc-using-jackson-json?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Personally I love Jackson library - it helps mapping JSON object to/from Java's POJO.

Take a look at MKYONG's tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/ (download ZIP with project).
Or take a look at this thread: [Parsing JSON in Spring MVC using Jackson JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019562/parsing-json-in-spring-mvc-using-jackson-json)