# Reading Content-Type application/json in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Like in [trying-to-use-spring-boot-rest-to-read-json-string-from-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313687/trying-to-use-spring-boot-rest-to-read-json-string-from-post) I want to read a json payload from a POST request in a Spring RestController. Using the content type "text/plain" there is no problem, but with "application/json" the deserialization fails and I get a MessageNotReadable exception. But actually the content couldn't be simpler, it is just an empty json object "{}". Could it be that a required converter is missing?
I use Spring Root version 1.2.3.RELEASE.

**Coding Example**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deepdefinitions", method = POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Definitions createOrUpdateDefinitions(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) throws IOException { ... }
```

**Curl Call**

```
curl -H  "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{}' http://localhost:8080/deepdefinitions
```

**Error**

```
{"timestamp":1434397457853,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@122f9ce3; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@122f9ce3; line: 1, column: 1]","path":"/deepdefinitions"}
```

Comment: You should use  headers = "Accept=application/json"  in '@RequestMapping' and pass the serialized object in '@RequestBody' to your controller method

Comment: Show the exact exception/stack trace please.

Comment: @Darshan, the "headers" in RequestMapping does not change the behaviour. I update the question with a coding example.

Answer (score 2):

From [Spring REST guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20190402042245/https://spring.io/understanding/rest):

> The `Accept` and `Content-Type` HTTP headers can be used to describe the content being sent or requested within an HTTP request. The client may set `Accept` to `application/json` if it is requesting a response in JSON. Conversely, when sending data, setting the `Content-Type` to `application/xml` tells the client that the data being sent in the request is XML.

It appears your Controller is processing only Accept header:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deepdefinitions", method = POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
```

You need to change it to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deepdefinitions", method = POST, headers = "Accept=application/json, Content-type=application/json")
```

There are also `consumes` and `produces` [*elements*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) available in `@RequestMapping` annotation.

The [Spring MVC documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers) recommends:

> Although you can match to `Content-Type` and `Accept` header values using media type wild cards (for example "content-type=text/*" will match to "text/plain" and "text/html"), it is recommended to use the `consumes` and `produces` conditions respectively instead. They are intended specifically for that purpose.

---

Going by your related post, you should change your method signature to:

```
@ResponseBody
public Definitions createOrUpdateDefinitions(@RequestBody String value, HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) throws IOException
```

I think you should also change you curl command as below. This is because `{}`(JavaScript *Object literal*) would map to a object and to map to a String you should use a empty string `''` literal.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '' http://localhost:8080/deepdefinitions
```

Comment: I had used the consumes condition before. It was Darsham who recommended to use the accept header. But the consumes leads to the same problem.