# Why this Json cannot be resolved from the HTTP request?

Tags: spring, curl

My code is based on `SpringBoot`, receives `post` request, resolves the `json` data and the use jdbc to execute.

```
public class ETLController {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("ETLService")
private ETLServiceImpl ETLServiceImpl;

@RequestMapping(value = "/sql", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
/**
 * @param sqlString 
 */    
public String identify(HttpServletRequest request) {

    //String sqlString, int maxRowNum, int maxColumnNum, int maxDuration, long startTime, String killQueryJob, int processResult
    System.out.println("request: "+request) ;
    String requestJson = request.getParameter("parametersJson");
    System.out.println("requestJson: "+requestJson) ;

    //Json parser
    JsonObject object = Json.parse(requestJson).asObject();

    //connection parameters
    String connString = object.get("connString").asString();
    String connUserName = object.get("connUserName").asString();
    String connPassWord = object.get("connPassWord").asString();

    //HQL query parameter
    String sqlString = object.get("sqlString").asString();
    int maxRowNum = object.get("maxRowNum").asInt();
    int maxColumnNum = object.get("maxColumnNum").asInt();
    int maxDuration = object.get("maxDuration").asInt();

    String sqlResult = ETLServiceImpl.executeShellScript(connString, connUserName, connPassWord, sqlString, maxRowNum, maxColumnNum, maxDuration);
    return sqlResult;
}
```

}

The curl command is as follows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  --data  '{"sqlString":"select room_id from dim.dim_room","connString":"jdbc:hive2://192.168.7.21:10001/","connUserName":"xxxx","connPassWord":"xxxx","maxRowNum":500,"maxColumnNum":10,"maxDuration":6000}' http://192.168.7.24:xxx/etl/sql
```

However, when I send the post request via curl, the parameter cannot be resolved and the `requestJson` is always null.

Why does this issue happen and how to address it?

---

The stacktrace:

```
2017-11-03 14:45:32.290 ERROR 181818 --- [nio-9162-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: string is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: string is null
        at com.eclipsesource.json.Json.parse(Json.java:292) ~[minimal-json-0.9.4.jar!/:na]
        at com.lz.web.action.etl.ETLController.identify(ETLController.java:39) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

Comment: You should decide whether you wish to send a POST request or a GET request. Your curl input is wrong for POST requests (it shouldn't contain parameter name such as "parametersJson", it should only contain the JSON content), and your server looks for a parameter as if it expects a GET request.

Comment: please add/update your question with error stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to use Spring Boot REST to Read JSON String from POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313687/trying-to-use-spring-boot-rest-to-read-json-string-from-post)

Comment: @Eran Thx for your reply. The command didn't contain the parameter name at first, but didn't work.

Comment: @SuperDelta because you are sending a POST request but your server seems to expect a GET request.

Comment: @SuperDelta please try the answer given by me. It will work for you. Thank You for updating your stacktrace :)

Comment: @VikrantKashyap  yes! thx for your code! I've learnt something!

Comment: @VikrantKashyap By the way, why my code does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a Pojo Class with class member which should be same as the keys available in the `JSON` you pass.

```
public class ConnectionString{

    private String sqlString;
    private String connString;
    private String connUserName;
    private String connPassWord; 
    private Long maxRowNum ;
    private Long maxColumnNum;
    private Long maxDuration;

    //all getters and setters.
  }
```

Now do a simple change in your method `identify()` to receive it directly as a Java Object.

try this method definition (see changed parameter)

```
public String identify(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody ConnectionString connectionString){

  //here how receive your data you passed using curl.
   System.out.println(connectionString.getSqlString());

   // this will print the value you passed as a body.
}
```

you also need to edit your curl body json data you passed like remove the key `parametersJson`

try this

```
'{"sqlString":"select room_id from dim.dim_room","connString":"jdbc:hive2://192.168.7.21:10001/","connUserName":"xxxx","connPassWord":"xxxx","maxRowNum":500,"maxColumnNum":10,"maxDuration":6000}'
```

instead of

```
'parametersJson='{"sqlString":"select room_id from dim.dim_room","connString":"jdbc:hive2://192.168.7.21:10001/","connUserName":"xxxx","connPassWord":"xxxx","maxRowNum":500,"maxColumnNum":10,"maxDuration":6000}''
```

> Note - Spring automatically change you `requestbody` data into the `JavaObject`. Spring internally used `jackson-databind` jar classes to perform this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can try below

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  -d  '{"sqlString":"select room_id from dim.dim_room","connString":"jdbc:hive2://192.168.7.21:10001/","connUserName":"magic","connPassWord":"w8spDGCJVMG3J2MWio5X","maxRowNum":500,"maxColumnNum":10,"maxDuration":6000}' http://192.168.7.24:xxx/etl/sql
```

Comment: You should explain what you have update and why you believe this would work

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
public String identify(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String parametersJson){...}
```

Comment: if you receive it as a `String` then it need to be converted into a `Java Object ` to perform further tasks. Thank You :)

Comment: Yes. Anyway you are doing same JsonObject object = Json.parse(requestJson).asObject();