# How to create angularjs springboot application that stores data to a mysql database. using json

Tags: mysql, json, angularjs, spring, hibernate

I'm kinda stuck on this topic.

This is what i already found out.
A good tutorial was :

Using MySQL in Spring Boot via Spring Data JPA and Hibernate
http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/

I also found some information how to make single page application with hsqldb.
But i really want to create something that permanent saves the users data to the database using mysql.

But in order to use angular http i need json. Can i convert the urls like

/create?email=[email]&name=[name]

To json how should i proceed. Does anyone knows good tutorials on this. Or are there better way's to proceed.

Comment: Check jhipster project, it can generate for you a full stack angularjs+springboot with a database of your choice. https://jhipster.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest/handy way to consuming JSON with Spring Boot is using a Java class that resembles your JSON (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6019761).

So, you can follow the [tutorial](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/) you linked, then use a controller like this one to handle JSONs:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @RequestMapping(
      value = "/user/create",
      method = RequestMethod.POST,
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {

    try {
      // Handle the User object here
      userDao.save(user);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }  

  // ...

}
```

Receiving a JSON like this (at the url `/user/create`):

```
{email: "john@doe.com", name: "John Doe"}
```

An user will be saved in your database.

---

**Responding with JSON**

Moreover, if you want to send a response as JSON from your controller you should create a java object then send it back as response, within the `ResponseEntity` object.

For example, suppose to have this class:

```
public class SuccessDto {

  private String success;

  public SuccessDto(String success) {
    this.success = success;
  }

}
```

You can change your controller in this way:

```
public ResponseEntity<SuccessDto> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {

  // ...

  return new ResponseEntity<>(
    new SuccessDto("true"),
    HttpStatus.OK
  );
}
```

and you will have this JSON as response

```
{success: "true"}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have already managed to use it with HSQLDB, it's juste a matter of database properties (like the JDBC URL) and schema initialization.

Can you provide the code sample of the controller,  how you save the data (via a Repository or a simple DAO ?) and the application.properties