# Redirect at @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have something for ajax login through spring security:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/entry.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEntry(){
    return isAuthenticated()? "redirect:/logout.jsp":"entry";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/postLogout.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getPostLogout(){
    return "{success:true, logout:true, session:false}";
}
```

The flow is that when receive a call to /entry.html, it will check and choose to

- redirect to `/logout.jsp` => handled by spring security and then redirect to `/postLogout.html` => response JSON
- resolve to view `entry`, which is a jsp contain only a json string

I would like to know if I can use `@ResponseBody` in `getEntry()` without using an jsp to write just a json value?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to return JSON from Spring is [through Jackson](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-mapping-json-converter).

I'd create a custom return Object:

```
public class MyReturnObject{
private boolean success;
private boolean session;
private boolean logout;
// + getters and setters
// + 3-arg constructor
}
```

and write the controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/postLogout.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody 
public MyreturnObject getPostLogout(){
    return new ReturnObject(true,true,false);
}
```

Spring+Jackson will take care of serializing the Object to JSON and setting the correct mime type. See [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908632#5908632) for a full working version.