# Spring MVC 3 and Ajax library advice

Tags: ajax, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc

I'm developing a webapp with Hibernate+Spring 3 (Spring MVC, JSP): I'd like to create some divs with AJAX style (i.e. no need to refresh all the page, independent update of each div).

I'd like a good advice about which AJAX library to use (in conjunction with Spring 3 MVC + JSP) and, if possible, where to find some code snippets.

I know very little of AJAX libraries, JSONs and how to integrate them, but I have good knowledge of Javascript and Spring (and how callbacks work). I'd like to write as less code as possible, particularly in the jsps.

My Webapp will display an updated (every 5 minutes) POJO in a div and perform some operations between different domain objects in the other div when user press a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct use JQuery

Here 
http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

you can find working examples to use Jquery+JSON+Spring MVC.

and this question can help you with server side configuration:
[JQuery, Spring MVC @RequestBody and JSON - making it work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908847#5908847)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It is very easy to use and has very good ajax support.

In addition to that it has quite a lot of plugins and components.