# send json to server spring 3.x

Tags: jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

i want to send json to server using Spring 3.x, i use annotation @RequestBody, but my controller don't called.

Please, send me a complete example, if any, I'm trying to use example in 
http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/ but it doesn't work. Here is a javascript code

```
function sendAjax() {
var person = new Object();
person.firstname = "Firsname";
person.lastname = "Lastname";

jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: "person", 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: person, 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data.firstname + " " + data.lastname);
    } 
});}
```

And my controller is

```
@Controller public class AjaxController {

@RequestMapping(value="person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Person getRequest(@RequestBody Person person) {        
    System.out.println(person.getFirstname() + " " + person.getLastname());
    return new Person("Return", "Body");
}}
```

my xml file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />               
<context:component-scan base-package="com.synisys.spring.test.controllers" />
<context:annotation-config/> 

 <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? Is there any log output?

Comment: Nothing happens. My controller just doesn't called. if i remove @RequestBody in my controller, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you have

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
```

and also

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
  <list>
    <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

In your spring xml conf file.

Comment: read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908847#5908847 i think it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax call add

```
var dat = JSON.stringify({
    "firstname " : firstname ,
    "lastname ": lastname 
});

jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: "person", 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: person, 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data.firstname + " " + data.lastname);
    } 
});
```

and make sure you add related dependency (if you are using maven Spring mvc)