# 415 Unsupported Media Type with Spring 3.2

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to insert and/or update data into the database using the `PUT` method via JSON using jQuery 1.6, (Jackson **2.1.1** and Spring **3.2.0**).

The JS code is as follows.

```
 var itemsArray=[];
 var id;

function insertOrUpdate()
{
    var i=0;

    $('input[name="txtCharge[]"]').each(function()
    {
        isNaN($(this).val())||$(this).val()==''?itemsArray[i][2]='':itemsArray[i][2]=$(this).val();
        i++;
    });                

    $.ajax({
        headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        datatype:"json",
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/wagafashion/ajax/InsertZoneCharge.htm",
        data: "items=" + JSON.stringify(itemsArray)+"&zoneId="+id+"&t="+new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(e)
        {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

The method inside the Spring controller which is mapped with the URL is as follows.

```
@RequestMapping(value=("ajax/InsertZoneCharge"), method=RequestMethod.PUT, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String insertZoneCharge(@RequestBody final MultiValueMap<String, String > data, final HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String message="";
    try
    {
        Map<String, String> params = data.toSingleValueMap();
        if(params.get("zoneId")==null||params.get("zoneId").equals("")||params.get("items")==null||params.get("items").equals(""))
        {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        else
        {
            message=zoneChargeService.insertZoneCharge(params.get("zoneId"), params.get("items"));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        message="An error occured. Data can not be saved.";
        Logger.getLogger(ZoneCharge.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return message;
}
```

The server responds as the question implies,

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

The header information looks like the following.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/wagafashion/ajax/InsertZoneCharge.htm
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:352
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=72AAFCC832C29D14FFA937D00D428A81
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/wagafashion/admin_side/ZoneCharge.htm
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
items=[[1,10,"12.35"],[2,10.5,"16.00"],[3,11,"20.00"],[4,11.5,"30.00"],[5,12,"40.00"],[6,12.5,"50.00"],[7,13,"60.00"],[8,13.5,"70.00"],[9,14,""],[10,14.5,""],[11,15,""],[12,15.5,""],[13,16,""],[14,16.5,""],[15,17,""],[16,17.5,""],[17,18,""],[18,18.5,""],[19,19,""],[20,19.5,""],[24,20,""],[25,20.5,""],[26,21,""],[41,21.5,""]]&zoneId=45&t=1359485680332
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:1048
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 29 Jan 2013 18:54:40 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

---

The entire `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file is as follows.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="validatorbeans" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" >
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
              p:supportedMediaTypes="application/json"
              class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
        <property name="favorParameter" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
        <property name="mediaTypes" >
            <value>
                atom=application/atom+xml
                html=text/html
                json=application/json
                *=*/*
            </value>
        </property>                    
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
</beans>
```

It works when I remove `@RequestBody final MultiValueMap<String, String > data`, a method parameter and simply use `@PathVariable` to accept request parameters.

Comment: *"It works when ..."* Do you then actually see the String changed into some JSON structure? And what if you add `<property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />`, or if you remove `register-defaults="false"` from `<mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">`?

Comment: @Arjan - Tried both the ways still not working unfortunately.

Comment: See also the comments at CodeChimp's answer!

Comment: So am I dealing with wrong request payload?

Comment: Above, `data: "items=" + JSON.stringify(itemsArray)+"&zoneId="+id+"&t="+new Date().getTime()` indeed is not JSON. Well, the value of `items` is JSON, but the full payload itself has multiple parameters, like `items` and `zoneId` and is not pure JSON. That's very much okay if you're sending it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` though (which is the jQuery default). As an aside, note that you can also have jQuery [create the content](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server) for you: `{items: ..., id: ...}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content type that the browser sends, `Content-Type: application/json`, does not seem to match `@RequestBody final MultiValueMap<String, String > data`.

Either:

- Send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (in which case you could easier use [HttpPutFormContentFilter](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5628) instead).
- Or: change this into something like `@RequestBody final MyDTO data` as explained in [JQuery, Spring MVC @RequestBody and JSON - making it work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908632#5908632).

Comment: I'm really very grateful to you. Thanks again.

Comment: ...but I doubt you've tested it this quickly?

Comment: Yes it worked. Tested again providing some input data and the expected changes have been made to the database. Thanks.

Comment: @Arjan Could you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102452/spring-mvc-415-unsupported-media-type/18103943?noredirect=1#comment26502825_18103943

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the way to solve it was removing @RequestBody and then taking the data from the request (with IOUtils from apache commons). It should be noted that I used the received data just for logging js errors.

```
/**
 * this method logs with log4j the received js errors 
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/jsloggerservice/{applicationName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void jsLogger(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        String message = IOUtils.toString( request.getInputStream());
        log.info("JAVASCRIPT-ERROR: " + message);
        response.getWriter().write("OK");
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this be really needed?

Comment: The benefit of at least *trying* this is that if the 415 is due to a deserialization issue (it was in my case) after getting the request and trying to deserialize it the issue/exception is more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In the server side, in Spring 3, you need this:

```
<bean id = "mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" class = "org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

<!-- starting Spring MVC annotation usage，handling request and annotation pojo mapping-->
<bean class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" >
    <property name= "messageConverters" >
         <list>
            <ref bean= "mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
         </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring 4 uses `mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.
Without `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` bean declaration, you can also use `@RequestBody`, while by declaring it we can set `mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to `messageConverters`. This is concluded by phenomena that I observed, if wrong please correct.

Answer (score -1):

I think your browser is not supporting whatever your returning.  An explaination of an [HTTP 415](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html) seems to indicate this.  What is the server sending as the Content-Type in the response?

Comment: Nope, it's a server side error indicating it cannot *create* any response. And the browser sends `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: According to the W3C: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html , the error is produced when "The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."  Your request payload is not in JSON format, but its says its Content-Type is JSON.  Your request payload looks to be a standard form posting.

Comment: I think your *answer* is wrong, but in your comment you're right about *"payload is not in JSON format"*. I didn't even notice that. I'm not sure if Spring would then throw a 415, or a 400 or even 500. I assume that, even if the payload were valid JSON, Spring would still not match it to `@RequestBody final MultiValueMap<String, String>`. (I can see how it could match really flat JSON structures, as in basic key-value pairs. But if it's just a little hierarchical, then I'd not know how Spring/Jackson would [convert that](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding) in a usable way?)

Answer (score -1):

Just in case somebody encounters this: I had two Methods

void setLevel (Level level)
void setLevel (String level)

in the Class annotated with @RequestBody and that also caused a 415.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this answers the original poster's question?

Comment: I encountered this SO thread while googling the error message (The Subject of the OPs question) and thought it might help other people that find this thread the way I did. So it basically only answers the subject, not the whole question.

Comment: In that case, this is probably better suited to be left as a comment on the question rather than posted as an answer.

Comment: Ah ok, next time I'll try that.