# Javascript delete sql row in spring

Tags: javascript, sql, spring, spring-mvc

My biggest problem about this question is I do not quite know how to phrase it.  In javascript, if a delete button is called it runs the following function

```
$scope.delete = function(){
            var params = {
                username: 'thisGuy'
            };
            $http.delete(afHttp.baseUrl, params)
                .success(function(data) {
                });
    }
```

while in spring I have

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{blah}")
public void getDeleteMssg(@RequestBody Person userName) throws Exception {
    dao.delete(userName);
}
```

and an interface that

```
@Delete("delete from People where userName = #{userName}")
void delete(Person userName) throws Exception;
```

Here is my problem.  When I do this, in my chrome console, I get the error 415 (Unsupported Media Type).  And if I change my javascript to be  $http.post(afHttp.baseUrl, params) it uses my add function on spring (instead of delete) and adds another username to the server which is not right.  Can someone help me figure this out, or at least a good search word to find myself.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590640/415-unsupported-media-type-with-spring-3-2

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the error you are getting is after the call is returned from your controller's delete method or its when you are requested the delete url ?

Also try adding this annotations to your delete method

```
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
```