# spring-mvc:415 (Unsupported Media Type) jquery

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have checked answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590640/415-unsupported-media-type-with-spring-3-2),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102452/spring-mvc-415-unsupported-media-type) but something is not working properly for me. my question is the same I am getting 415 -unsupported media type when I tried to submit form. Even I checked with postman client it is showing same. so it must be something from my back end code. but I am not able to get it what.

Here's my jquery code

```
    home='<%=request.getContextPath()%>';
function companyRegistration(){
    var add = {}
    var address={};
    add["type"] = $("#type").val();
    add["companyName"] = $("#companyName").val();
    add["regNumber"] = $("#regNumber").val();
    add["dob"] = $("#dob").val();
    add["email"] = $("#email").val();
    add["password"] = $("#password").val();
    add["confirmPassword"] = $("#cpassword").val();
    address["line1"] = $("#line1").val();
    address["line2"] = $("#line2").val();
    address["state"] = $("#state").val();
    address["country"] = $("#country").val();
    address["zipCode"] = $("#zipCode").val();
    add["address"]=address;
    add["enabled"]=false;
    console.log("search: ", add);
console.log("stringify data:",JSON.stringify(add));
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
     /*      headers: { 
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            },  */
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        url : home+"/addCompany",
        data : JSON.stringify(add),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            alert(data)

        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            alert(e);

        },done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
});
```

here its corresponding back end code

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/addCompany",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public@ResponseBody String userLogin(@RequestBody CompanyRegVO user,HttpServletRequest req){
    logger.debug("signUp user:"+user);
     // get reCAPTCHA request param
    String gRecaptchaResponse = req.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response");
    boolean isVerified= Verify.verifyGcaptchResponse(gRecaptchaResponse);
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString="";       
    System.out.println("signUp user:"+user);
    Integer id=null;
    try{
        if(isVerified){
            id = signupHandler.process(user);
            if(id!=null){
                logger.debug("ID in controller:"+id);

                emailHandler.sendVerificationMail(id,user.getEmail());
                System.out.println("user create successfully"); 

            }
            jsonString=mapper.writeValueAsString("User creaated successfully");

        }
         else
        jsonString= mapper.writeValueAsString("please verify that you are not a robot");
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            jsonString=mapper.writeValueAsString(e.getMessage());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {

        }
        return jsonString;
    }


    return "success";

   }
```

I tried by adding headers and content-type and accept. thus my config class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={EmailHandler.class,CompanyRegVO.class,CompanyInfoDao.class,MainController.class,MyDBAuthenticationService.class,CompanyRegVO.class,ApplicationContextConfig.class,HibernateUtil.class,SendMail.class})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Bean
  public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
      ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      // Load property in message/validator.properties
      rb.setBasenames(new String[] { "messages/validator" });
      return rb;
  }

  @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
  public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return viewResolver;
  }
```

this CompanyRegVO

```
public class CompanyRegVO {
private String companyName;
private Integer regNumber;
private String password;
private String confirmPassword;
private String type;
private String email;
private String dob;
private Boolean enabled;
private AddressVO address;
//getters and setters
}
```

I have Jackson-core,jackson-mapper-asl,jackson data-bind dependency in my POM. please let me know where it went wrong??

Edit 1:
One thing if I remove @RequestBody annotation is working fine
this my add object I got in console

and this my addressVO class

```
public class AddressVO {
 private String line1;
 private String line2;
 private Integer zipCode;
 private String state;
 private String country;
//getter and setter
}
```

Here its my data after stringification

stringify data: `{"type":"user","companyName":"k","regNumber":"0","dob":"16-10-1992","email":"vihangshah16@gmail.com","password":"12345678","confirmPassword":"12345678","address":{"line1":"l3","line2":"l2","state":"k","country":"i","zipCode":"12"},"enabled":false}`

Edit2:
Based on inputs here its what my network tab is showing

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/basicPages/addCompany
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
**Response Headers**
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1091
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 07 Jan 2017 06:11:32 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
**Request Headers**
view parsed
POST /basicPages/addCompany HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 253
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8080/basicPages/signUp
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0FFD6259AED6E75ABD62ED556AC125E4; oracle.uix=0^^GMT+5:30^p
**Request Payload**
view source
{type: "user", companyName: "k", regNumber: "1", dob: "16-10-1992", email: "v16@gmail.com",…}
address:{line1: "l1", line2: "", state: "g", country: "i", zipCode: "1234"}
companyName:"k"
confirmPassword:"12345678"
dob:"16-10-1992"
email:"v16@gmail.com"
enabled:false
password:"12345678"
regNumber:"1"
type:"user"
```

Comment: seems to me you are posting some HTML element back to server, that's where it happens. You can take a look at `JSON.stringify(add)` the `add` is not containing any element.

Comment: can you show that how you have created value of "add" variable?

Comment: Added please see once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why previous approach was not working but after I used JSOnSerilizable object then it worked successfully.
Below is my updated code.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonSerialize(using=CompanySerilizable.class)
public class SignUpVO {
    private String email;
    private Integer regNumber;
    private String companyName;
    private String dob;
    private String type;
    private String password;
    private String confirmPassword;
    private AddressVO address;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }
    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Integer getRegNumber() {
        return regNumber;
    }
    public void setRegNumber(Integer regNumber) {
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
    }
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public AddressVO getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(AddressVO address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SignUpVO [email=" + email + ", regNumber=" + regNumber + ", companyName=" + companyName + ", dob=" + dob
                + ", type=" + type + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }
}
```

and this is my serializable class

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;

public class CompanySerilizable extends JsonSerializer<SignUpVO> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(SignUpVO sign, JsonGenerator json, SerializerProvider sprov)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        json.writeStartObject();
        json.writeNumberField("regNumber", sign.getRegNumber());
        json.writeStringField("line1", sign.getAddress().getLine1());
        json.writeStringField("companyName", sign.getCompanyName());
        json.writeStringField("dob", sign.getDob());
        json.writeStringField("line2", sign.getAddress().getLine2());
        json.writeStringField("country", sign.getAddress().getCountry());
        json.writeStringField("state", sign.getAddress().getState());
        json.writeNumberField("zipCode", sign.getAddress().getZipCode());
        json.writeStringField("password", sign.getPassword());
        json.writeStringField("confirmPassword", sign.getConfirmPassword());
        json.writeStringField("email", sign.getEmail());
        json.writeStringField("type", sign.getType());
        json.writeEndObject();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at couple of things:

This is what it looks like :

```
{
    "type": "user",
    "name": "teqni",
    "regNumber": "12345",
    "dob": "16-10-1992",
    "email": "vihangshah16@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678",
    "confirmPassword": "12345678",
    "line1": "f-12",
    "line2": "e city",
    "state": "ka",
    "country": "in",
    "zipCode": "1235"
}

It should have been :


{
    "type": "user",
    "name": "teqni",
    "regNumber": "12345",
    "dob": "16-10-1992",
    "email": "vihangshah16@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678",
    "confirmPassword": "12345678",
    "address":{
        "line1": "f-12",
        "line2": "e city",
       "state": "ka",
       "country": "in",
      "zipCode": "1235"
     }
}
```

AddressVO object should be embedded . incorrect json I feel.

Try adding @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) to the pojo class

Comment: can you please where should I exactly add this? and one more thing I have added addressVO data into CompanyRegVO andRemoved addressVO still I got same result

Comment: Add it on top of POJO classes CompanyRegVO , addressVO. Issue is because of @RequestBody annotation , since spring doesnt able to map the input request to an instance of CompanyRegVO it throws this exception and also try adding produces="application/json" since you added consumes for safety reasons(not mandatory as spring is smart enough to decide that). JsonIgnoreUnknownProperties ensure to ignore unknown properties during jackson conversion

Comment: did you have this project in github ? share the link

Comment: can you remove @RequestBody CompanyRegVO and check whether this error has gone away ? then we can find the root cause and fix it accordingly

Comment: But if I remove that then how my form data will be bind to VO object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132430/discussion-between-lowcool-and-barath).

Comment: First of all to find out whether exception is due to that binding, secondly please change the request structure to match the POJO as mentioned the difference above.

Comment: :have added my proj in git hub [link](https://github.com/vihang16/spring-mvc)..please see once

Comment: did it work ?? . Looks like you changed your POJO classes

Comment: Nope..previous POJO didn't work so added like this it also didn't work

Comment: and one more thing if I remove @RequestBody annotation is working fine

Comment: I already shared the code which worked. Why it is not working in your code ?? Please see the network tab under developer tools of the browser and find the request body how it is sent .Meanwhile I will try to go through the link and find anything odd.