# Spring PUT and DELETE: Request method not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, httprequest, http-delete, http-put

I'm trying to use RequestMethod.PUT and RequestMethod.DELETE in Spring MVC controller. My controller has a @RequestMapping for PUT and DELETE, but despite that, I'm getting error when trying to use it:

```
Request method 'GET'/'POST' not supported
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ModelAndView updateUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, @PathVariable long id) {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/user/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable long id) {
    ...
}
```

I've added also filters in `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Spring form for PUT:

```
<form:form id="registerForm" method="put" action="${user.id}" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">
```

Generated HTML:

```
<form id="registerForm" class="form-horizontal" action="13" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>
```

I know, that if browser isn't supporting PUT/DELETE then POST/GET is used, but why my controller method is not called?

Comment: Isn't "13" a quite strange form action?

Comment: No, why? This '13' is added to actual address, so in real it is: `/admin/user/13`. Using POST in this case worked perfectly.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250439/can-spring-mvc-have-request-parameters-for-an-http-put-method-or-must-i-use-pos

Comment: Are you sure that a) your filter is executed and b) you have added the filter config to your `pom.xml` and not your `web.xml`? Where do you see the 'Method not supported' error?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Of course, filters are in my `web.xml`. I see this error in the browser and in GlassFish Server log.

Comment: If the browser sends POST and GET and you only respond to PUT and DELETE, you will never get called.

Comment: Just use POST for update and delete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PUT and DELETE methods in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629653/using-put-and-delete-methods-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Ok, I know I can use GET/POST, but shouldn't it also works with PUT/DELETE? Why my browser sends POST/GET? How can I fix that?

Comment: @bartex9 did you solve it ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't. Couldn't make PUT/DELETE working in my project.