# mapping json to a pojo using MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter and POST

Tags: ajax, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to make something very similar to this post using Spring MVC 3.1:

[JQuery, Spring MVC @RequestBody and JSON - making it work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together)

and trying to get the response as a custom class such as "FooBar" in the example.

my ajax call looks like this:

```
// var rule = "giveThisATry";
var rule = {
    id : 1,
    name : {
        name1 : "1",
        name2 : "2",
        name3 : "3",
        name4 : "4"
    }
};
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/spring2/save",
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    //contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data : rule,
    success : function(data) {
        alert("success saveRule: " + data);
    },
    error : function(request, status, error) {
        alert("error saveRule: " + request.responseText);
    }
});
```

and my rest method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/save")
public @ResponseBody MyClass save(@RequestBody MyClass instance, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return MyDB.Save(instance);
}
```

Now no matter what I do, Spring would not map the ajax call to this method.
Also if i uncomment the line in my ajax call :

```
contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Chrome would change the "request-method" to "OPTIONS" :

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8020
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8020/JQueryPOC/src/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11
Response Headersview source
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 15 Jun 2012 15:07:19 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Now how can i test/debug/have control over the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter so that i can map the json to a pojo using requestbody or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see that you have to convert the `rule` to a Json String - this plugin may help you:http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/
`data : $.toJSON(rule)`

Comment: Thank you Biju. Actually my code was suffering from a few mistakes one of which you pointed out. Another one was that I was trying to make a cross domain ajax call which was solved after putting service and client codes in the same project. Also I was overriding my FooBar class default constructor, which caused problems in serialization.