# @RequestBody and @ResponseBody annotations in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Can someone explain the `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody` annotations in Spring 3? What are they for? Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

There is a whole Section in the docs called [16.3.3.4 Mapping the request body with the @RequestBody annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody). And one called [16.3.3.5 Mapping the response body with the @ResponseBody annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody). I suggest you consult those sections. Also relevant: [`@RequestBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) javadocs, [`@ResponseBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) javadocs

Usage examples would be something like this:

Using a JavaScript-library like JQuery, you would post a JSON-Object like this:

```
{ "firstName" : "Elmer", "lastName" : "Fudd" }
```

Your controller method would look like this:

```
// controller
@ResponseBody @RequestMapping("/description")
public Description getDescription(@RequestBody UserStats stats){
    return new Description(stats.getFirstName() + " " + stats.getLastname() + " hates wacky wabbits");
}

// domain / value objects
public class UserStats{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // + getters, setters
}
public class Description{
    private String description;
    // + getters, setters, constructor
}
```

Now if you have [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) on your classpath (and have an [`<mvc:annotation-driven>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) setup), Spring would convert the incoming JSON to a UserStats object from the post body (because you added the `@RequestBody` annotation) and it would serialize the returned object to JSON (because you added the `@ResponseBody` annotation). So the Browser / Client would see this JSON result:

```
{ "description" : "Elmer Fudd hates wacky wabbits" }
```

See this previous answer of mine for a complete working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5908632/342852

Note: RequestBody / ResponseBody is of course not limited to JSON, both can handle multiple formats, including plain text and XML, but JSON is probably the most used format.

---

### Update

Ever since Spring 4.x, you usually won't use `@ResponseBody` on method level, but rather `@RestController` on class level, with the same effect.

Here is a quote from the official [Spring MVC documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller):

> `@RestController` is a [composed annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-meta-annotations) that is itself *meta-annotated*
>   with `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` to indicate a controller whose
>   every method inherits the type-level `@ResponseBody` annotation and,
>   therefore, writes directly to the response body versus view resolution
>   and rendering with an HTML template.

Comment: In your linked answer, you used the `@ResponseBody` annotation on the parameter, not the method. I get errors trying to put it on the method, so I'm assuming your other answer is correct. I think you should have `getDescription(@RequestBody UserStats stats)` above.

Comment: @Patrick no, `@RequestBody` is on the parameter, `@ResponseBody` is on the method. important difference!

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Sorry, I didn't mean to mention `@ResponseBody` at all. As you just said, `@RequestBody` goes on the parameter, right? But in the above answer, you have it on the method.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd `@RequestBody` is actually still required, `@ResponseBody` is implicit when using `@RestController`. Pls correct your answer, it has too many upvotes to be false!

Comment: @SumitJain to be fair: this answer was around before `@RestController` and was changed when it was introduced

Comment: And yes, I had confused RequestBody and ResponseBody. Fixed.

Comment: @PSyLoCKe you need some serialization provider. Either Jackson or JAXB are picked up automatically, if present. Others need configuration. But Spring itself doesn't serialize anything.

Answer (score 40):

**[@RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)** : Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the body of the HTTP request.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/something", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void handle(@RequestBody String body, Writer writer) throws IOException {
    writer.write(body);
}
```

**[@ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html)** annotation can be put on a method and indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name).

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/something", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public  @ResponseBody String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Alternatively, we can use [@RestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) annotation in place of `@Controller` annotation. This will remove the need to using `@ResponseBody`.

[for more details](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody)

Answer (score 7):

Below is an example of a method in a Java controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public HttpStatus something(@RequestBody MyModel myModel) 
{
    return HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

By using @RequestBody annotation you will get your values mapped with the model you created in your system for handling any specific call. While by using @ResponseBody you can send anything back to the place from where the request was generated. Both things will be mapped easily without writing any custom parser etc.

Answer (score 1):

**@RestController** is a composed annotation that is itself meta-annotated with **@Controller** and **@ResponseBody** to indicate a controller whose every method inherits the type-level @ResponseBody annotation and, therefore, writes directly to the response body versus view resolution and rendering with an HTML template
So instead of marking your class as **@Controller** use **@RestController** instead and remove the @requestbody annotation from you class

heres an example:
@RestController

```
public class MomController {

    @RequestMapping("/sugar") // maped to the url /sugar
    public String addSugar() {
        return "here is your sugar";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.programmingfree.springshop.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.programmingfree.springshop.dao.UserShop;
import com.programmingfree.springshop.domain.User;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/shop/user")
public class SpringShopController {

 UserShop userShop=new UserShop();

 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
 public User getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
  User user=userShop.getUserById(id);
  return user;
 }


 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
 public List<User> getAllUsers() {
  List<User> users=userShop.getAllUsers();
  return users;
 }


}
```

In the above example they going to display all user and particular id details now I want to use both id and name,

1) localhost:8093/plejson/shop/user <---this link will display all user details
2) localhost:8093/plejson/shop/user/11 <----if i use 11 in link means, it will display particular user 11 details

now I want to use both id and name

localhost:8093/plejson/shop/user/11/raju <-----------------like this
it means we can use any one in this please help me out.....

Comment: Please correct formatting of the answer and code sample.

Comment: Please describe how this code helps the questioner. Thank you.