# Required String parameter is not present error in Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I try to make an AJAX query to my controller in Spring MVC.

My action code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEvent(@RequestParam(value = "start_date") String start_date, @RequestParam(value = "end_date") String end_date, @RequestParam(value = "text") String text, @RequestParam(value = "userId") String userId){
    //some code    
}
```

My Ajax query is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:     {
                start_date:   scheduler.getEvent(id).start_date,
                end_date:  scheduler.getEvent(id).end_date,
                text: scheduler.getEvent(id).text,
                userId: userId
        },
        success:function(result){
         //here some code
        }
    });
```

But I got an error:

> Required String parameter ''start_date is not present

Why?
As I know I presented it like `(@RequestParam(value = "start_date") String start_date`

**UDP**
Now I give 404
My class to take data

```
public class EventData {
    public String end_date;
    public String start_date;
    public String text;
    public String userId;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

My js AJAX call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    // data: eventData,
    processData: false,
    data:    JSON.stringify({
        "start_date":   scheduler.getEventStartDate(id),
        "end_date":  scheduler.getEventEndDate(id),
        "text": scheduler.getEventText(id),
        "userId": "1"
    }),
```

And controller action:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEvent(@RequestBody EventData eventData){    
}
```

And JSON data is:

```
end_date: "2013-10-03T20:05:00.000Z"
start_date: "2013-10-03T20:00:00.000Z"
text: "gfsgsdgs"
userId: "1"
```

Comment: Does jquery serialize `data` elements as request parameters? As url-encoded-form params?

Comment: It is just variable from JS file

Comment: In both of your examples, have you tried actually inspecting your POST request and making sure it is passing the desired values?  What is it showing in each case?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On the server side you expect your request parameters as query strings but on client side you send a json object. To bind a json you will need to create a single class holding all your parameters and use the @RequestBody annotation instead of @RequestParam.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEvent(@RequestBody CommandBean commandBean){
    //some code
}
```

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-reponsebody-spring) a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON you are trying to send? You can capture it with Firebug or Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: Can you write, how I can see it in Google Chrome?

Comment: In request payload it shows start_date=Tue+Oct+01+2013+00%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B0400+(Russian+Standard+Time)&end_date=Tue+Oct+01+2013+00%3A05%3A00+GMT%2B0400+(Russian+Standard+Time)&text=New+event&userId=

Comment: That's weird it seems jquery sends data as query string by default. This is not nice in case of POST requests. Try to add processData: false flag in your .ajax request and wrap your data element in a JSON.stringify({...}) call. like: http://pastebin.com/JLKgLivC

to see request payloads in chrome: tools > developer tools > network tab

Comment: I found a problem. it was in returning value of controller. I doesn't set JSP page and it returnes 404 always.Your answer was correct

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.. I solved it by specifying the config params in the post request:

```
var config = {
    transformRequest : angular.identity,
    headers: { "Content-Type": undefined }
}

$http.post('/getAllData', inputData, *config*).success(function(data,status) {
    $scope.loader.loading = false;
})
```

**config** was the parameter I included and it started working.. 
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Boot Code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEvent(@RequestParam(value = "start_date") String start_date, @RequestParam(value = "end_date") String end_date, @RequestParam(value = "text") String text, @RequestParam(value = "userId") String userId){
    //some code    
}
```

**Postman Request Link to be send:** Add the parameters and value using Parmas in postman and see the below request link.

```
http://localhost:8080/events/add?start_date=*someValue*&end_date=*someValue*&text=*someValue*&userId=*someValue*
```