# Required String parameter 'licenceplate' is not present"

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-http

I checked in different existing questions that was asked for similar problem but I didn't get any help for my problem.
In fact I can't use @RequestBody like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619088/required-string-parameter-is-not-present-error-in-spring-mvc) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-annotations-in-spring).

I'm trying to pas some parameters from Angular controller to a Spring MVC controller, but I'm getting this error message 
`errorCode:500
message:"Required String parameter 'licenceplate' is not present"`
here is my Angular Service:

```
myApp.httpEnterVehicle = function(levelNumber, placeNumber, licenceplate, placeType) {
    return $http.put("/myApp/rest/vehicle/entervehicle", {
        params : {
            'licenceplate' : licenceplate,
            'placeType' : placeType, 
            'placeNumber' : placeNumber, 
            'levelNumber' : levelNumber
        },
    });
};
```

and nothing was detected on my backend side wich seems to be strange

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/entervehicle", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> enterNewVehicle(@RequestParam("licenceplate") String licenceplate, @RequestParam("placeType") String placeType, @RequestParam("levelNumber") int levelNumber, @RequestParam("placeNumber") int placeNumber){
....
}
```

do you have any idea what's going on? I already tried toc check the content of my Angular service param and they are correct :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect put request call, it should look like below

```
$http.put('url', //1st parameter
   {}, //request body
   {} //request configuration here
);
```

If you compare you current `put` call you can see what wrong thing you were doing. You just need to pass `{}`(empty object) in request body the pass your config object in place of `request body`

```
myApp.httpEnterVehicle = function(levelNumber, placeNumber, licenceplate, placeType) {
    return $http.put("/myApp/rest/vehicle/entervehicle",
      {}, //added blank object as request body
      {
        params : {
            'licenceplate' : licenceplate,
            'placeType' : placeType, 
            'placeNumber' : placeNumber, 
            'levelNumber' : levelNumber
        },
    });
};
```