# Can spring map POST parameters by a way other than @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am using `@RestController`s with an application where all requests are `POST` requests ... As I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619088/required-string-parameter-is-not-present-error-in-spring-mvc) , you can't map individual post parameters to individual method arguments, rather you need to wrap all the parameters in an object and then use this object as a method parameter annotated with `@RequestBody` thus

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestotp",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String requestOTP( @RequestParam(value="idNumber") String idNumber , @RequestParam(value="applicationId") String applicationId) {
        return customerService.requestOTP(idNumber, applicationId);
```

will not work with a `POST` request of body `{"idNumber":"345","applicationId":"64536"}`

MY issue is that I have **A LOT** of `POST` requests , each with only one or two parameters, It will be tedious to create all these objects just to receive the requests inside ... so is there any other way similar to the way where get request parameters (URL parameters) are handled ?

Comment: Your request body is in json format and your are receiving data in form type. please change request body into form type not in json type

Comment: I am trying from advanced rest client, I can't see form-type ... do you mean `multipart/form-data` ?

Comment: no you should send data in format of form-data

Comment: you can bind all your params in single class, and accept it as @RequestBody , and get parameter according to your requirement using getter setter.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes there are two ways -

first - the way you are doing just you need to do is append these parameter with url, no need to give them in body.
url will be like - baseurl+/requestotp?idNumber=123&applicationId=123

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestotp",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String requestOTP( @RequestParam(value="idNumber") String idNumber , @RequestParam(value="applicationId") String applicationId) {
        return customerService.requestOTP(idNumber, applicationId);
```

second- you can use map as follows

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/requestotp",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String requestOTP( @RequestBody Map<String,Object> body) {
        return customerService.requestOTP(body.get("idNumber").toString(), body.get("applicationId").toString());
```

Comment: good ...but what if I want to apply automatic validation on the parameters `@Valid` ...I think I wont be able to use Map, right ?

Comment: yes If you will use map then you have to do validation manually

Comment: What if one of my parameters is an array of strings? I suppose I can pipe-delimit and then split on the back end, but is there a native solution?

Answer (score 6):

I have change your code please check it

**DTO Class**

```
public class DTO1 {


private String idNumber;
private String applicationId;

public String getIdNumber() {
    return idNumber;
}

public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
    this.idNumber = idNumber;
}

public String getApplicationId() {
    return applicationId;
}

public void setApplicationId(String applicationId) {
    this.applicationId = applicationId;
}
```

}

Rest Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestotp",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String requestOTP( @RequestBody DTO1 dto){
    System.out.println(dto.getApplicationId()+"  (------)  "+dto.getIdNumber());
    return "";
}
```

Request Type -- application/json
{"idNumber":"345","applicationId":"64536"}

OR

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestotp",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String requestOTP( @RequestBody String dto){
    System.out.println(dto);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Actually my question exactly is how to avoid this approach :) ....  because I will need to make a DTO for every request

Comment: yes it can be for that you have to change your request type into form-data

Comment: you can just post the answer here so that every one gets the benefit

Comment: also I am restricted by the frontend (Angular) sending json

Comment: Please check my update answer, I think 2nd ANS will resolve your problem. :)

Comment: but what if I have two parameters ?

Comment: @osamayaccoub it will return you complete json data you have to break   that using JSONOBject or any

Comment: Would you still create a POJO for one single key-value pair?