# Post request from angular to spring boot server params are not seen

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I am quite new with angular and spring boot and I am trying to send a post request from angular to the spring server but it gives me bad request with message "Required String parameter 'key' is not present"

however the post is sent with request payload containing the key and the value, but it is a request payload not a form data and I don't know whether it differs or not :/
spring code: 
`https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oRMAtICuS0TaoPVMgDxd1ApGALnCOq-o`
[image: Angular code]
[image: Post request form]

Comment: Post your spring boot code as well

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oRMAtICuS0TaoPVMgDxd1ApGALnCOq-o

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19620057/2700586

Comment: Thank you finally it worked by adding RequestBody instead of RequestParam.