# Spring MVC - PUT - JSON serialize to Java Object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, serialization

I am trying to write a REST PUT method and I am not sure how you get the body that the requestor is sending. For example, he is going to send a Person object serialized to JSON and I want to serialize the JSON back to a Person object.

I couldn't find much on Spring PUT, but here is what I have:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Person registerPerson(@PathVariable String siteId, @ModelAttribute("personForm") Person user) throws Exception {

        //some Logic

    }
```

I don't think I am doing this correctly. Does @ModelAttribute automatically serialize?

Comment: _body that the requestor_ Check out `@RequestBody`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis where would I put that at the top under request mapping?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-reponsebody-spring

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Person registerPerson(@RequestBody Person user) throws Exception {

        //some Logic

    }
```