# android json data to spring mvc4

Tags: java, android, json, spring-mvc, annotations

I am new to using Spring mvc4 annotation . In all i want to do is using spring mvc as a web service . so i would be thankful if anyone could provide me a solution for it.

My android code is as:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost( "http://localhost:8080/datarequest");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


            json.put("action", "check_login");
            json.put("username","name");
            json.put("password", "password");


        JSONArray postjson = new JSONArray();
        postjson.put(json);

        httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);

        System.out.println(postjson);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

so far i wrote the web service as:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/datarequest")
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMethod(ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println("GET");

    return "hello";
}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public String getMethod(ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println("POST");
    System.out.println("here i want to print json data send from the android ");


    return "hello";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) and map it to required class structure. You can refer this SO question [@RequestBody and @ReponseBody spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-reponsebody-spring).

To test, you can map it to String. See below example.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String getMethod(@RequestHeader(value="json") String headerStr) {
    System.out.println("POST");
    System.out.println(s);
    return "hello";
}
```

You can add below [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.5.1) entry in your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Instead of putting values in on json String, why don't you put it as 3 different headers named `action`, `username` & `password`. And retrieve it in controller independently. But I think you do not want to change android code, this method is ok.

Comment: My application doesn't contain only these three parameters it contains many parameters so i used json for it .@ Naman Gala