# How to effectively handle multiple user inputs with @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using `@RequestParam` to catch the front-end user input and pass it to the back end through controller and save it to the database.

So far controller handles the request like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myURL", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCustomer(
            @RequestParam("customerFirstName") String customerFirstName,
            @RequestParam("customerLastName") String customerLastName,) {

        Customer customer = customerService.saveCustomer(
                customerFirstName, customerLastName);
        return null;
    }
```

Well I guess this is fine when I only have two `@RequestParam` for two arguements, but I am facing some table that has more than 10 params, I think by using @RequestParam is apparently not realistic, is there another around this?

Comment: Why do you say it's not realistic?

Comment: @cadams it is time consuming and confusing to write method that takes 10 parameters dont u think?

Comment: Perhaps just perform the user input outside of the argument list, and store the information in variables, and then use those variables as parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the customer directly.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myURL", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCustomer(Customer customer) {

    customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
    return null;
}
```

Spring can databind POJOs as long as you have a no-args constructor and setters for your properties.

Comment: so currently at the front-end i have forms that the user will type in and I use the `@RequestParam` to catch these data, how do you make sure I can pass in the user input data to `Customer` if do what you suggested?

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is no need to use @RequestParam in your case

Answer (score 0):

You should create a provider to use JSON, so you can send complex Java\JS objects and not just primitives.

Comment: There's no need for JSON. Spring can databind form properties to POJOs

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Can you modify your answer to add databind form properties to POJOs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to deal with multiple @RequestParam you can always opt for a bean class approach.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myURL", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCustomer(
        @RequestBody Customer customer) {
    return null;
}
```

Bean:

```
public class Customer{
    private String customerFirstName;
    private String customerLastName;
    //constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-reponsebody-spring) out for more info on @RequestBody