# Paypal IPN Request handling with Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, paypal

I am wanting to extend the functionality of a Spring App to include an HTTP endpoint to receive Paypal Instant Payment Notifications.

Paypal sends these in the HTTP body like so:

> mc_gross=19.95&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LPLWNMTBWMFAY&tax=0.00&address_street=1+Main+St&payment_date=20%3A12%3A59+Jan+13%2C+2009+PST&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&first_name=Test&mc_fee=0.88&address_country_code=US&address_name=Test+User&notify_version=2.6&custom=&payer_status=verified&address_country=United+States&address_city=San+Jose&quantity=1&verify_sign=AtkOfCXbDm2hu0ZELryHFjY-Vb7PAUvS6nMXgysbElEn9v-1XcmSoGtf&payer_email=gpmac_1231902590_per%40paypal.com&txn_id=61E67681CH3238416&payment_type=instant&last_name=User&address_state=CA&receiver_email=gpmac_1231902686_biz%40paypal.com&payment_fee=0.88&receiver_id=S8XGHLYDW9T3S&txn_type=express_checkout&item_name=&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=19.95&shipping=0.00

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Do I need to define a concrete class to define the request body e.g.

**Request Class**

```
    public class PaypalIPNRequest {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String mc_gross;
    private String protection_eligibility;
    private String address_street;
    ...


    public PaypalIPNRequest() {
    }

    //getters setters
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Override
@Auditable
@RequestMapping(value = "/ipnRequest.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void ipnRequest(@RequestBody final PaypalIPNRequest request) {
}
```

As stated in this SO answer: [@RequestBody and @ResponseBody annotations in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-spring)

What happens though if Paypal change their IPN request in the future, will this break?

Is there a better way to pass the request body without having a specific class?

Could I use HttpServletRequest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have done in the past is use `com.paypal.base.ipn.IPNMessage` to validate and retrieve from the request (like you proposed) just the fields that where important to me instead of mapping the entire request body to a concrete class, i.e.:

```
private final static String PAYPAL_WEB_IPN_TXN_PARAM = "txn_id";
private final static String PAYPAL_WEB_IPN_AMOUNT_PARAM = "mc_gross";
private final static String PAYPAL_WEB_IPN_PAYMENT_STATUS_PARAM = "payment_status";
private final static String PAYPAL_WEB_IPN_PAYMENT_STATUS = "Completed";

@Resource(name = "payPalConfigurationMap")
private Map<String, String> configurationMap;

private OAuthTokenCredential oAuthTokenCredential;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(configurationMap);
    PayPalResource.initConfig(properties);

    oAuthTokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(
            configurationMap.get(Constants.CLIENT_ID),
            configurationMap.get(Constants.CLIENT_SECRET),
            configurationMap
    );
}


public DonationDTO validateWebIPN(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    IPNMessage ipnlistener = new IPNMessage(request, configurationMap);
    boolean isIpnVerified = ipnlistener.validate();

    String paymentStatus = ipnlistener.getIpnValue(PAYPAL_WEB_IPN_PAYMENT_STATUS_PARAM);

    if (isIpnVerified && paymentStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(PAYPAL_WEB_IPN_PAYMENT_STATUS)) {
        String amount = ipnlistener.getIpnValue(PAYPAL_WEB_IPN_AMOUNT_PARAM);
        String tx = ipnlistener.getIpnValue(PAYPAL_WEB_IPN_TXN_PARAM);

        // irrelevant code

        return donationDTO;
    }else{
        String exceptionMessage = "Problem when requesting info from PayPal service";
        logger.error(exceptionMessage);
        throw new Exception(exceptionMessage);
    }
}
```

This way, unless Paypal changes the name of the fields (which shouldn't happen) you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Just for clarification is this in the Spring controller or is this your own class you created?

Comment: This is my own class. I have a class annotated with `@RestController` which receives the IPN request from Paypal and call this method above which is in another class with `@Service`.

Comment: Thanks, slightly off topic but what content type did you use for handling IPN requests. I am getting HTTP 415 errors from Spring

Comment: I used `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`.