# Can someone please clarify @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have done some reading and research on `@RequestBody` but I am still unable to wrap my thick head around the purpose of it.

Given the scenario:

- RESTful API takes only `bookName` from a user and returns the `authorName` of the book.
- The `@RequestBody` annotation is added on the `getAuthor` method which takes the `bookName` as a parameter.

From what I read in a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-annotations-in-spring) question answered, how does that apply in this scenario? What does it mean by converting `A` to `B` and then `B` to `A` so that users can see it as a JSON object. I'm so confused!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the javadoc:

> Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the body
>   of the web request. The body of the request is passed through an
>   HttpMessageConverter to resolve the method argument depending on the
>   content type of the request. Optionally, automatic validation can be
>   applied by annotating the argument with @Valid.

In your example there is no point in using `@RequestBody`. You want to get the author name corresponding to a book

You send  GET`/books/myBook/author`

The Controller would be

```
@RestController
public class BooksRestController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/books/{bookName}/author", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String,String> getAuthor(@PathVariable bookName){
        ...
        Map<String,String> author = new HashMap<String,String>();
        author.put("author",bookAuthor);
        return author;
    }
}
```

The response would be `{"author":"whoever"}`.

Now imagine that you want to create a book. That's when you would use `@RequestBody`, to automatically parse the JSON sent in the HTTP POST body into a `Book` object.

**Request:** POST `/books` - Body `{"name" : "SomeBook", "author":"SomeAuthor"}`

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class BooksRestController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/books", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Book createBook(@RequestBody Book book){
        ...
        //save book
        book = bookService.save(book);
        return book;
        //Book is going to be serialized as JSON because of the implicit 
        //@ResponseBody annotation from @RestController
    }
```

**Book.class:**

```
public class Book{
    private String name;
    private String author;
    //getters setters;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, it was clear and concise. 

You mentioned that:
"Now imagine that you want to create a book. That's when you would use @RequestBody, to automatically parse the JSON sent in the HTTP POST body into a Book object."

Does it also convert it back to a JSON object and display it back on the browser / return to the user?

Comment: Nope, to achieve that yo need to specify `@ResponseBody` in the return parameter of the method. However, as you can see in the example, the controller is anotated with `@RestController`, which implicitly assumes that annotation (from the javadoc: `Types that carry this annotation are treated as controllers where @RequestMapping methods assume @ResponseBody semantics by default.`). I you were using `@Controller` instead, you would have to add the annotation yourself.