# MissingServletRequestParameterException with PostMapping in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm getting this error when I try to create an instance of an Object and store it into a database:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException
```

The code for the method:

```
@PostMapping(path="accounts/add", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public
@ResponseBody
String addAccount(@RequestParam String accountNumber, @RequestParam String accountName ) {
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setAccountName(accountName);
    account.setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
    accountRepository.save(account);
    return "Saved";
}
```

When I use PostMan and try to enter the JSON in, it gives me this message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The exception indicates that you're not providing the parameter `accountNumber`, `accountName`, or both. Doesn't the exception specify which one is missing?

Comment: It specifies that I am missing the accountNumber, which is boggling to me when I specify it in the JSON.

Comment: So, it works, it puts the data into the database. But, it puts all of it into one column, which is not what I want. Why does it do that, and what can I do to fix it?

I actually took care of it on my own! Thanks for clarifying a few things!

Answer (score 0):

Since your POSTing (or PUTing?) JSON as the content body, you cannot use `@RequestParam` to deconstruct it. That is used for query or form parameters. You need to specify a single method parameter with `@RequestBody`, which is a class that looks something like the following.

```
public class Account {
    public String accountNumber;
    public String accountName;

    // setters and getters removed for brevity
}
```

See this answer for more info: [@RequestBody and @ResponseBody annotations in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-annotations-in-spring)