# How to bind HTTP params with @RequestBody in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have some entity:

```
public class Entity {
    String name;
    String age;
}
```

and entity's fields come to me as HTTP params:

"name=alex&age=30"

How can i set auto converting HTTP params to my entity's fields with `@RequestBody` annotation?

I did it properly with JSON in request body, but I cannot do it with normal HTTP params.

What message converter should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate.There are dozens of examples here.Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-annotations-in-spring

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis they all about binding request body to entity, and not about binding HTTP params to entity

Comment: So  you need them in the headers and not the body?

Comment: check this link May be it's help full for you. http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-api-example/

Comment: That doesn't look like HTTP params, are you sure they come like that? Usually a request body looks more like "name=alex&age=30" (unless it's JSON of course).

Comment: @jvdmr ye you are correct. I need to bind something like "name=alex&age=30" to my entity.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis i was wrong a bit, params come to me in body in format "name=alex&age=30"

Comment: @coolsv so you need something equal to @JsonProperty("first-name") ?

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-annotations-in-spring may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to the parameters of your `@RequestMapping` (or `@PostMapping`, ...) annotation should fix it.