# Spring boot read json parameter

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I trying to read my JSON parameter but when I try to read with `system.out.println` I get this

```
%7B%22rfx%22%3Atrue%2C%22rfp%22%3Afalse%2C%22rfp_x%22%3Afalse%2C%22allclassification%22%3Afalse%2C%22eu%22%
```

What should I do to read my `JSON` file!

```
@PostMapping("/filtreregioncloser")
public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody String filterRegion) {
    System.out.println(filterRegion);
    return null;      
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@RequestBody and @ResponseBody annotations in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-annotations-in-spring)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only geting a string in your `@RequestBody` dont send a JSON, just send the string