# got 400 error after jQuery send json request to spring mvc server

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

My spring3.1 mvc server can response right json result by add `@ResponseBody`, should no problem on spring setting file. The servlet.xml included

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

I put jackson jars in classpath.

And my html file also set contentType to 'application/json" in .ajaxSetup() method. And I can see post header is right in Firebug.

I also tried include json2.js to call JSON.stringify method.

The json format sample:

```
{"link":"http:xxxxx","ticker":"xxxxx"}
```

The responseBody class is Document:

```
public class Document implements Serializable{
   public String getLink(){...}
   public String setLink(String link){...}
   public String getTicker(){...}
   public String setTicker(String ticker){...}
}
```

The controller code:

```
public class LoadFile  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    @RequestMapping(value="/loadFile",method=RequestMethod.POST)                                                                                                                                                  
    public @ResponseBody Document loadFile(@RequestBody Document document){ 
        ...
    }
}
```

The html code:

```
$(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    $.ajaxSetup({                                                                                                                                                                                               
        contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8" 
    });                                                                                                                                                       
    $.post( url, { link: link, ticker:ticker },                                                                                                                                            
        function( data ) {  
           ....
        },"json"
    );
}
```

Document class can return as a json object when added `@ResponseBody`, but when as a `@RequestBody`, the server returns 400 error.  Not sure what happens.

Comment: can you provide more code, javascript and controller code ?

Comment: fixed by reference [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908847#5908847  I guess gae jackson lib have some conflict with spring, so have to explicit the converter package name. But still use RequestBody, not ModelAttribute

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem recently. For me, it was adding the "" around the variable names which gave me the 400 error. Try it like this:

```
{link:"http:xxxxx",ticker:"xxxxx"}
```

Also make sure that your variables correspond to your database, depending how Spring3.1 handles the data. (e.g in the correct order)

I hope that helps you.

Comment: sorry, my json sample is from firebug. but code is {link:"http:xxxxx",ticker:"xxxxx"}, so should not be the cause

Answer (score 0):

replace `@RequestBody` by `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: the method called but document's property is null. Base spring document, it can create document from form or session.  How can create document from jquery post?

Comment: it should work, make sure that link and ticker have a value. you can look at them on firebug

Comment: firebug show the two parameter have right value but server side's document still do not have any property.