# JSON to Spring - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: json, spring, rest

I'm new to Spring, and I've been trying to figure out the best way to send JSON to a spring REST controller.  I've read through some similar issues on StackExchange, but trying the solutions doesn't seem to help, so I appear to still be missing something.

On the Spring side:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping(value="/register",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody UserWrapper registerUser(@RequestBody RegisterParams params) {

        logger.info("REGISTER POST!");
        User newUser = userService.registerUser(params.getEmail(),params.getPassword(),params.getName());

        return new UserWrapper(newUser);
    }
private class RegisterParams implements Serializable {
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String name;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

And on the javascript side (name, password, and email variables contain strings):

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/gameserver/user/register',
        data: JSON.stringify({name:name,password:password,email:email}),
        success: onSuccess,
        error:onError
        ,contentType:'application/json'
        ,dataType:'json'
    });
```

And the chrome output:

```
Request URL:http://192.168.56.101:8080/gameserver/user/register
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:71
Content-Type:application/json
Host:192.168.56.101:8080
Origin:http://192.168.56.101:8080
Referer:http://192.168.56.101:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview source
{name:nickname, password:somepass, email:something@email.com}
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:986
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 20 Jun 2014 11:18:17 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

> HTTP Status 400 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The request sent by the client was syntactically
>   incorrect.

I appreciate the help, and sorry if I missed something from a similar post.

Comment: did u add <mvc:annotation-driven/> in spring configuration.

Comment: @RameshKotha - I'm using the servlet-context.xml generated by STS for a basic Spring MVC.  it contains
 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven />
 Which I assume is set up for the mvc annotations?

Comment: @Gyst, could you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scope of `RegisterParams` to `public static`. I don't have much experience with Spring JSON mapping but other frameworks don't handle private nested classes very well by default.

Are you using Jackson?  If so, have you registered `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`? See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together) for more info about using Jackson and Spring MVC together.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to leverage the Jackson Libraries here, register the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and inject the same in your RequestMappingHandlerAdapter. This is how I am using it
Use this in your spring configuration file -

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonRequestConverter" />
        </beans:list>           
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jsonRequestConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
```

if you are using maven, you can use following dependency for Jackson Libraries

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
  </dependency>
```