# How to force jQuery DataTable to send requests as application/json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, encoding, datatable

Is there way to force DataTable to use application/json instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded when sending requests?
The only way I can think of is to write my own DataTable.ajax(), but maybe there's a better way...?

(The goal is to handle the server side with Spring as described in this post: [JQuery, Spring MVC @RequestBody and JSON - making it work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together).)

Comment: Have you consider using [jQuery.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)?

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov "Its use is not recommended" and I can kinda see why... I guess I will just intercept DataTable.ajax()