# ExtJS and Spring MVC file upload failed

Tags: java, spring, extjs

I am trying to upload file with additional fields but the browser shows the error:

"HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()."

Here are my Java codes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
void saveUser(
        @RequestBody SystemUser systemUser,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + error.getCode() + " - "
                    + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
    }
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

        // Creating the directory to store file
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
        File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "img");
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        // Create the file on server
        File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                + fileName);
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();
        systemUser.setImageFile(fileName);
        systemUserService.create(systemUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here's my JS Code:

```
userformAdd = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
          alias   : 'widget.usersform',
          title   : 'Add User',
          id : 'add',
          width   : 350,
          layout  : 'fit',
          resizable: false,
          closeAction: 'hide',
          modal   : true,
          config  : {
            recordIndex : 0,
            action : ''
          },
          items   : [{
            xtype : 'form',
            layout: 'anchor',
            bodyStyle: {
              background: 'none',
              padding: '10px',
              border: '0'
            },
            defaults: {
              xtype : 'textfield',
              anchor: '100%'
            },
            items : [{
              name  : 'id',
              fieldLabel: 'ID'
            },{
              name: 'fullName',
              fieldLabel: 'Full Name'
            },{
              name: 'address1',
              fieldLabel: 'Address 1'
            },{
              name: 'address2',
              fieldLabel: 'Address 2'
            },{
              name: 'contact1',
              fieldLabel: 'Contact 1'
            },{
              name: 'contact2',
              fieldLabel: 'Contact 2'
             },{
                    xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                    name: 'file',
                    fieldLabel: 'File',
                    labelWidth: 50,
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    anchor: '100%',
                    buttonText: 'Select a File...'
                }]
          }],
          buttons: [{
            text: 'OK',
            handler : function (btn){
                var values = btn.up('window').down('form').getForm();
                values.submit({
                    url: 'module/save.do',
                    success: function(fp, o) {
                        var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')[0];
                        grid.getStore().load();
                    }
                });
                    userformAdd.close();
                ;
            }
          },{
            text    : 'Reset',
            handler : function () { 
              this.up('window').down('form').getForm().reset(); 
            }
          },{
            text   : 'Cancel',
            handler: function () { 
              this.up('window').close();
            }
          }]
        });
```

And I've also used the bean for the multipartResolver in the xml configuration:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000" />
</bean>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...Any suggestion/help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to return `void` from saveUser you need to return an **[ResponseStatus](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html)** to signal a successful processing and you don't need the [ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK) 
public void saveUser(...)
```

If you review the Interface definition for @ResponseBody you will see that it indicates the method should return a value.

> public @interface ResponseBody
>   Annotation that indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body. Supported for annotated handler methods in Servlet environments.

Another problem you may have is that you are declaring a @RequestBody parameter with a value of `SystemUser` To enable automatic conversion you can use @EnableWebMvc or implement a message converter..

Here's an example of how you can **[Implement a MessageConveter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908632#5908632)**

Another thing I see suspect is that you have your controller mapped to `/save.do` and your JSON is posting to `/module/save.do`

Comment: There's problem with HTTP itself (Error 400)...it didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Try again with the method declaration I provided. @ResponseBody is stating, `return a value` but you have a `void` definition.

Comment: I declared the annotations as you provided and removed the @ResponseBody but the problem is still the same...

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi Do you have a MessageConverter for your SystemUser RequestBody?

Comment: Do you have <mvc:annotation-driven /> or @EnableWebMvc in your config?

Comment: no i dont have any..but excluding the file upload, the method was working fine without the MessageConverter.

Comment: yes i also have <mvc:annotation-driven /> in my config

Comment: Wait a second. Why is your post going to /module/save.do and your controller is mapped to /save.do?

Comment: that is not a problem here...i have declared @RequestMapping("/module") at the top of the class...

Comment: The problem is solved just by removing the @RequestBody in the SystemUSer param...
Thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

In your ExtJS form, you need to have fileUpload set to true and method POST