# Spring MVC @RequestBody not working with jquery ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

Here is my ajax request

```
var dataModel = {name1:"value1", name2:"value2"};

$.ajax({
              url: "/testURL",
              type: "POST",
              async: false,
              contentType: "application/json",
              data: dataModel,
              success: function(response) {

              }

    })
```

Here is my relevant snippet from spring xml

```
<annotation-driven>
        <!-- Message converters are added to use custom object mapper in  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.
            StringHttpMessageConverter is required to avoid MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter from converting a string into json.
        -->
        <message-converters>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </message-converters>
    </annotation-driven>
```

Here is my controller mapping

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testURL", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String add(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody CustomObject customObject) throws Exception {}
```

But My request does not even reach to controller. As soon as I remove `@RequestBody CustomObject customObject` it works. But I want to map the json request to 
    CustomObject with `@RequestBody` which is not happening . **Not sure what i am missing here ?**

In fact when I inspect `request.getParameterMap()` it displays empty but as soon as I remove `contentType: "application/json"` I see parameter map gets populated but still
    then get below error

```
`The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method`
```

Here is my  CustomObject definition

```
public class CustomObject implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name1;
private String name2;

//getters and setters
}
```

Already gone through [JQuery, Spring MVC @RequestBody and JSON - making it work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908632#5908632) but did not help

Answer (score 4):

> In fact when I inspect request.getParameterMap() it displays empty but
>   as soon as I remove contentType: "application/json"

That is right. Reason is with `contentType: "application/json"` jquery internally convert the data into string. so there is no request parameter. Without `contentType: "application/json"` , default `contentType' is form data . So data sent is converted to request parameters based on delimiters`&`and`=`

Also try `data: JSON.stringify(dataModel)`, it should work

Comment: I have data in list, when I will do JSON.stringify(data) it will become blank, `editForm.credentials=[{attribute:'username', value:'t2'}, {attribute:'password', value:'t2'}];` same is working in postman.`$.ajax({url : getContextPath()+ "/abc/update",
  type : 'POST',
  data : dataTosend,
  contentType : 'application/json',
  success : function(data) {}
     });`