# Unsupported Media type 415 @RequestBody Not working But @RequestParam is working

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Model class and a controller. I am posting json type data in the body of post man. But each time i'm getting an unsupported media type 415 error.
Here is My Model class :

```
public class Model1 {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    public Model1() {
        System.out.println("In the Model");
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model1 [name=" + name + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }
}
```

And My Controller is :

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class EcomController { 
    @RequestMapping(value="/getLogin", method=RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getLoginStatus(@RequestBody Model1 name){
        return "successfully called Post"+name.toString();
    }
}
```

I have used HttpServletRequest in the place of @RequestBody and it worked. But Why its not woking when I am using @RequestBody?

This is the postman snapshot.
[Here is the image of request from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnvPK.png)

```
{
    "name": "anshsh",
    "password": "vbvfjh"
}
```

[This is the Screen shot of headers used in the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSC9G.png)

Comment: Are you passing `Content-Type` header with value `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in the request ?

Comment: how are you calling the endpoint?

Comment: I am calling this post API from PostMan. I have used content-Type header with value JSON. this is the Json : {
    "name": "anshsh",
    "password": "vbvfjh"
}

Comment: I personally run your implementation and it works fine. Does the request body have the appropriate JSON format?

Comment: just to be certain - the content-type header value is "application/json"?

Comment: What do you have on Params tab?

Comment: @Janar Yes. I have used the same header-type.

Comment: can you post a picture of the headers tab in postman?

Comment: @ManolisPap In the screen shot of postman, I have disabled the param tab. But If you are concerned about the params then here is that: `name: gdgdg`

Comment: Just to be sure, have you set `server.servlet.context-path=/Ecom` ?

Comment: @ManolisPap Dont know how to set this value.

Comment: Add it to `application.properties` file. In your image you are trying to access the API from /Ecom, to do that you need to set the Context Path on `application.properties`

Comment: Can you check the application logs and post the stack trace here as well?

Comment: Where exactly did you set the `/Ecom` context path if it's neither on the code you provided nor on the `application.properties` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake in my configuration file.
adding `<mvc:annotation-driven />` solved the problem.

Explanation :
My program was running well but problem was on Mapping the String (Json) into java objects. So there was some issue in default Mapping classes. Although, jackson was present in class-path, It wasn't working.
`<mvc:annotation-driven />`
this tag would register the HandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter required to dispatch requests to your @Controllers. In addition, it also applies some defaults based on what is present in your classpath. Such as: *Support for reading and writing JSON, if Jackson is on the classpath.*

Answer (score 0):

There are two areas to check for such issues.

1. Add `Content-type` as `application/json` in the request (which you
   have already done)
2. Make sure you have `jackson` (core and data-bind)
   libraries in the classpath

The point #2 is to make sure that the application is able to convert between JSON and Java types.

To narrow down the issue further, check the logs and try GET API and see if the Java object is converted to JSON string.

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together/5908632#5908632) for complete working code.

Comment: GET APIs are working very well: `@RequestMapping(value="/getUser", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getUser(){
  return "some String value";
 }`

Comment: Thanks for your support. The link was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put @ResponseBody there

also some example would be

```
@RestController 
public class EcomController { 
    @PostMapping("/getLogin")
    public String getLoginStatus(@RequestBody Model1 name){
        return "successfully called Post"+name.toString();
    } 
}
```

If you keep getting error, I think the problem is the servlet didn't find your controller registered.. Can you give more information in detail like the log when you try to compile?